# OpenCV lib and WM

Tags: opencv

I just made an application using the OpenCV lib, and will be great if I can use this computer vision application on my PDA, which has Windows Mobile 6.0 on it.

Do you have any idea about how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio, just create an embedded project. Check out the [Windows Mobile Development Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx) for more information. Unless it's a very simple application or you're working with very low resolution images I would be surprised if you were able to get acceptable performance though.